# Problems with matrix dimension - Python

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to get matrix T in python and don't know what my mistake is. This is my code:

```
c=dx/L  
s=dy/L  
cc=c**2     
ss=s**2     
cs=c*s  
T = np.matrix( ((cc, cs,-cc,-cs),                   
                (cs, ss,-cs,-ss),                   
                (-cc,-cs, cc, cs),
                (-cs,-ss, cs, ss))
```

The values that are given are dx, dy and L. If I want to run the script it just says:

```
"..../miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 240, in __new__
    raise ValueError("matrix must be 2-dimensional")
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional
```

Can anyone of you help me? I have no idea why the matrix should not be 2-dimensional. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to make T as an array:

```
T = np.array( ((cc, cs,-cc,-cs), 
              (cs, ss,-cs,-ss),
              (-cc,-cs, cc, cs),
              (-cs,-ss, cs, ss)) )
```

Matrixes in numpy module are only 2-dimensional, but arrays are N-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks! It works this way but it´s still a mistery to me why it doesn't work with np.matrix.

Comment: A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations. See more in numpy docs:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html